# Html.TextBoxFor bootstrap Date mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I've got this VMs' property:

```
[Required]
        [Display(Name = "Expiration date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
```

and this code in model:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExpirationDate, String.Format("0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Model.ExpirationDate),new{@class="form-control", type = "date"})
```

but only receive this:
[image]

I mean there is no date from view model. But value attribute is fill with date:
http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1380730052-clip-2kb.png

Actually the question: why does the date is not shown in input?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do this:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExpirationDate, new{ @class="form-control", type = "date"})`

Comment: What if you skip `type="date"`? Maybe its your browser that doesn't support inpt type date?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have it as a placeholder?  If so, I believe this should work (untested, though) -

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExpirationDate, String.Format("0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Model.ExpirationDate),new{@class="form-control", type = "date", placeholder = m.ExpirationDate})
```

Comment: Nope. Not as placeholder

Comment: Oh I noticed something - try swapping the format to MM/dd/yyyy - if you'll notice, that's what the value is for the current placeholder, and you're passing in dd/MM/yyyy - an invalid date.